# Getting Null values at the place of data which was removed manually from excel file

Tags: excel, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I was reading an excel file with one column,

```
country 
india 
India 
india 
India 
india
```

dataframe i got from this data : df.show()

```
+-------+ |country| +-------+ |
 india | 
| India |
 | india | 
| India | 
| india | 
+-------+
```

In the next step i removed last value from the excel file manually by backspace and saved the file,

file now :

```
country
 india 
India
india 
India
```

now when i run the same df.show(), this is what i get:

```
+-------+ |country| +-------+ |
india |
 |India |
 |india | 
|India | |
 null | 
+-------+
```

if i have removed the value why do i get a null value at its place?

and my code if someone needs it,

```
val spark = SparkSession

            .builder

            .appName("schemaTest")

            .master("local[*]")

            .getOrCreate()





val df = spark.read

         .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").

          option("header", "false").

          option("inferSchema", "true").

          option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "false").

          option("addColorColumns", "False").

          load("data/trimTest2.xlsx")



df.show()
```

Comment: All these are values are not headers they are just printed here like they are , all the values are inside a country column.

Comment: So, country is not in your file? Or it is? If it is, then why `option("header", "false")`?

Comment: I inserted a header so people here can read and understand my problem clearly, there was no header in my file, but i can add it makes no difference to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general answer, it can be applied to every programming language. It depends how the excel sheet got created but usually it gets created as a data structure with columns and rows. So let's say you create an excel with 10 columns and 10 rows and you fill every cell with data, if you backspace the data in the last row, your sheet will still be a 10x10 but the last row will have only empty values. Try to open it as .csv, you should see the last row as a sequence of separators.
You should have something like this:

```
data;data;data;
india;india;india;
;;;
```

Or if you deleted a column

```
data;india;;
data;india;;
data;india;;
```

To properly remove the row/column you have to remove it programmatically or either go to the excel and remove the row/column with right-click->delete row/column, not with backspace

Comment: `option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "false")` should ignore it, though, if not put an empty string in the dataframe

Comment: thank you now i get where my issue is originating from but is there a work around for this?